# Close the tracking privilege popup with the Esc key or a click outside

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page, user-experience

[image: Screenshot of expanded privilege tracking popup]

On one's Profile page, clicking on this gear button opens up a pop up, which doesn't close when the "Esc" key is pressed or when one clicks outside the popup. To close this list, you have to click on the button again.

Whereas clicking on other gear buttons for next badge or next tag badge, opens albeit a different menu, which can easily be closed with the Esc key or by clicking outside the popup.

It would be nice if the User interaction was consistent.

Comment: Related in MSE: _[Close menu that chooses between privilege and badge tracking by clicking anywhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278445/312043)_

Comment: *checks his privileges* I guess I can't close that popup.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: It's a 30k privilege!

Comment: Seems like you don't have privilege to close the pop-up.

Comment: Do you mind drawing a freehand circle around the "gear button" so I can find it more easily?